# How can I make a separate .html and .scss files for a component for a mobile version?

Tags: angular, architecture, progressive-web-apps

Is his possible to make Angular 7 pick up a certain template and style file and bring it to the user?

Sometimes I need completely different layout representations and @media isn't that comfortable especially when you need to restructure the whole page it's a mess with the code.

At the moment there is only one solution as I can see - it's hiding ng-templates (some parts of the code) for different devices.

I've read a lot of questions here but they are all old. I hope in this fast-changing IT world something may have changed recently and there is a good and elegant solution to cope with such tasks.

I tried to solve it in this manner -

```
(b) ? './app.component.html' : './test2.html';
```

but it doesn't work, unfortunately

I would appreciate any hints on that.

P.S.: I really like the structure of how NativeScript implemented it recently. It would be nice to have the same ability.

Comment: Build two different components, lazy import both of them.  Then use JavaScript to determine whether user is on mobile or not.  Throw that boolean into an ngIf for the parent component deciding which component to render.  That's been my solution anyway.

Comment: Angular uses a custom version of Webpack when creating builds, so you can use this guide to lazy load: https://webpack.js.org/guides/lazy-loading/

Comment: Sit down as a developer and rethink your architecture. Super components that greatly change their presentation based upon device context are a maintainability problem. Divide your problems and conquer them with smaller single purpose components.

Comment: @Bradd Thank you, a lot! I was racking my brain for a few days what's the best solution to implement that. But I cannot get the key of how I can dynamically pick the component I need. I usually used lazy loading for importing my separate modules, parts of an application. so you mean that with JavaScript I check the device and redirect to the certain url?

Comment: @Reactgular, Sure! I was trying to find a solution but I feel that I am not that skilled by now. That's why I wanted to ask more skilled people of how they've done that.

Comment: @Valaryo, you could redirect to a mobile/desktop friendly URL sure.  I haven't gone that path, but here is an excellent guide on how to do that: https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/how-to-lazy-load-components-in-angular-4-in-three-steps/

My solution was more basic.  Basically instead of trying to give one component two templates, give the parent component a template that ngIfs between two entirely different child components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an excellent example of a problem that can be solved with Lazy Loading Modules.

A great guide and video tutorial for doing this with routing can be found here:  https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/how-to-lazy-load-components-in-angular-4-in-three-steps/

Your problem is essentially that you don't know if your user is on a Desktop or Mobile at load time, so what you want to do is wait until your code can make that decision and then render the corresponding component.

My Solution:

1) Create two modules, one for all of your desktop components, another for all of your mobile components.

2a) Lazy Load both of these into your main AppModule according to the guide linked above

or

2b) Import all of the components in your AppModule if bundle size is a non-issue

3) Create a parent component who's only job is to determine if the user is Desktop or Mobile

`parent.component.ts` will have logic to determine if the user is mobile or desktop, and could do this with any number of window calculations or npm packages

`parent.component.html` will have the two components and an `ngIf` with the `isMobile` determining which component to render.

**Bonus points**

Isolate your logic by creating a single class for matching components and just importing different templates